# Is it possible to exclude a label in a storyboard from a generated .strings file?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard

I like to have some example text in storyboard labels that will be set at run-time.
This text should never be translated, and is only used to make the storyboard look more like the finished product.
I'd like to exclude that text from being in the .strings file that's generated every time I update the storyboard.
Is there any way to do that?

A way to indicate to the translator that this text isn't to be localized would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot exclude these labels from being in the string files, these files are an extract from the storyboard and thus need to be there.

A trick I use is to use a naming convention for these labels, so I know afterwards they don't need to be translated, for instance I would name a label "Username" -> "lbl_Username". It still looks decent enough in the Storyboard and I'm sure not to waste my time translating them when doing the localization